# Android - Center Logo in Custom Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to center my image logo in a custom toolbar, but I believe my hamburger icon is pushing the image to the right. It looks fine in Android Studio, but not on the device. I've been searching a long time for a fix to this but no luck. I've tried adding the image to the toolbar container itself and using center gravity but this also does not work.  My xml code for the main activity and tool bar is below, and my MainActivity.java code. Thanks for any help.

[hamburger icon pushing logo left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niMe2.jpg)

```
//custom_toolbar.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="675dp"
        android:background="#315c54"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:src="@drawable/grocers_logo"
            android:layout_gravity = "center_horizontal"
             />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="29dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="imageClick"
        android:src="@drawable/send"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.515"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
//activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--the root view must be the DrawerLayout-->
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"

   tools:context=".MainActivity"
   tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
       android:id="@+id/view_foods"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
       tools:context=".MainActivity">
       
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
 
   <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
       android:id="@+id/nav_view"
       android:layout_width="350dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       android:clickable="true"
   >

       <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
           android:id="@+id/view_pager"
           android:layout_width="323dp"
           android:layout_height="687dp"
           android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
           android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="255dp"
           app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/list_slidermenu"
           app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.087" />

       <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
           android:id="@+id/tabs"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
           android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
   
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

```
//MainActivity.java

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_toolbar);

        ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar();
        action.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)action.getCustomView().getParent();
        toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
        toolbar.getContentInsetEnd();
        toolbar.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);



        tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                switch (tab.getPosition())
                {
                    case 0:
                        MainActivity.drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
                        // your logic goes here!

                        break;

                    case 1:
                        MainActivity.drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
                        // your logic goes here!
                        break;

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }


            });

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.nav_open, R.string.nav_close);
       
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();


        displayFragment_MainActivity();

    }
```

Comment: "I've tried adding the image to the toolbar container itself and using center gravity but this also does not work." – You need to set the `layout_gravity` on the `<ImageView>` to `center`, not plain `gravity`. This would be the preferred method, btw. The current approach is adding unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, thanks!!

Comment: Still no dice. It does center in Android Studio, but the logo just disappears completely now in the emulator. I tried center_horizontal and just center.

Comment: Yeah I figured it was in ImageView, but thanks for the note. I feel like this is the way to go, but somethings keeping this from working.

Comment: I was just about to do that, sorry. Just updated the question. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're using this layout, but I've rearranged it and removed some unnecessary things, a couple which were suspect and might've cause the observed behavior: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QKIF95peNn24czuIyJToOICOrhHH8tAJ/view?usp=sharing. If this layout is only for the `Toolbar`, and not like the beginning of a whole `Activity` layout, then you can just remove the `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Runtime screenshot, with substitute images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdfLf.png.

Comment: It still doesn't work but that was very appreciated. I'm thinking this must go beyond my xml and has something to do with the way I'm setting up my toolbar. I tried the code from the link you provided: stackoverflow.com/a/41962801 and it at least displays the issue more easily since the background colors are different. Picture has been added to question.

Comment: Yikes. That sounds bad. I'll try to post any code related to the toolbar, thanks!

Comment: Ok... I've added the MainActivity.java file and activity_main.xml file to the question as well. This should be all code relevant to my toolbar.

Comment: OK, yeah, you are ending up with two, because the support `ActionBar` itself is a `Toolbar`, and that code is sticking your `Toolbar` inside the `ActionBar`. Then, the hamburger icon is being set on the `ActionBar`, so that's squeezing your `Toolbar` to the right a bit. The easiest way to do this is to turn off the default `ActionBar`, move your `<Toolbar>` into `activity_main`, and the set it as the support `ActionBar` in code. Then you'll have just the one, and everything will line up. Is that a possibility for you? Or do you need to keep the default `ActionBar` for whatever reason?

Comment: Ah! I see what your saying. Ok I'm going to give that a shot. I don't think I need the default Action Bar if the Tool Bar is serving the same purpose. This is my first venture into Android UI so I'm not surprised I did something ridiculous like that. I think I may need to do some reading. Thanks again...

Comment: No problem. Yeah, `ActionBar` is just a special designation for a `Toolbar` in an `Activity`, basically, so whether you use the default or your own, they're equivalent, but it's much easier to customize certain things when supply your own. Turning off the default is often done by simply changing the `Activity`'s theme's `parent` to a `NoActionBar` version, if available. Then it's just a matter of moving that `<Toolbar>`, `findViewById()`ing it, and calling `setSupportActionBar()` with it, and you're good to go. You shouldn't need any of that other `ActionBar`/`Toolbar` code that you have now.

Comment: Ok! Well two steps forward, one step back. I was able to get the ToolBar working without the action bar, and the logo is centered with a hamburger icon! But!... the DrawerLayout now takes up the entire screen instead of being place directly below the ToolBar, and I loose the fancy hamburger icon animation. Can you keep the animated hamburger icon without ActionBar? I'm sure I can manage to lower the DrawerLayout to be below the ToolBar. Looking back now when I first started, I think this why I nested the ActionBar and ToolBar, but didn't realize there was this overlapping functionality.

Comment: No worries. It sounds like you put the `<Toolbar>` inside the `<ConstraintLayout>` in `activity_main`. If so, then that animation is still there; the drawer just covers it before you can really see it. In the previous setup, the `ActionBar` was part of the top decor, and all of your stuff was laid out below that. To get that same look, you just need to pull the `<Toolbar>` out, and put it and the `<DrawerLayout>` both inside another `<ViewGroup>`; e.g., a vertical `<LinearLayout>`, like so: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RNkL8MUyQ-d8as4ee5PfMMxMF88_ZyAR/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: I see what you mean, yeah that's probably it. Alright giving that a go, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mike M. for this.

Custom ToolBar with centered logo. Please view comments for a full explanation of the solution.

```
//onCreate method

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // assigning ID of the toolbar to a variable
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // using toolbar as ActionBar
    toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
    toolbar.getContentInsetEnd();
    toolbar.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_drawer_layout);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, 
    R.string.nav_open, R.string.nav_close);

       
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

```
//activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="#315c54">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/grocers_logo" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/view_foods"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" />

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:clickable="true">

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="323dp"
                android:layout_height="687dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="255dp"
               />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
               />

        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```